# How To Convert Decimal to Binary in SQL Server when it Requires more Bytes than Datalength

Tags: sql-server

A value of `Decimal(4,0)` requires 5 bytes to store in SQL Server.  This is according to the documentation that says all [decimal and numeric types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746(v=sql.110).aspx) with precision 1-9 take 5 bytes.  Also the `DATALENGTH` function confirms:

```
select DATALENGTH(convert(Decimal(4,0),256)) result

result
-----------
5

(1 row(s) affected)
```

However, when I convert to `binary(5)` and then back to `decimal(4,0)` it truncates data.

```
DECLARE @myval decimal (4, 0);  
SET @myval = 257;  
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(4,0), CONVERT(varbinary(5), @myval)) result

result
---------------------------------------
1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

The last byte of the number is chopped off.  However, if I convert to binary(6) or more... I get the correct results:

```
DECLARE @myval decimal (4, 0);  
SET @myval = 257;  
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(4,0), CONVERT(binary(6), @myval)) result  

result
---------------------------------------
257

(1 row(s) affected)
```

What is happening?  If I need to store a binary representation of a decimal value, how do I know how many bytes will be needed?  Specifically, what is the generic formula to determine smallest number x of bytes required to convert decimal(p,s) to binary(x)?

I need to do some binary data marshaling into a service broker message so I need to convert some data of various types to a binary string.  Is there a more robust way to store decimal values in binary than using cast/convert?

Comment: The internal / binary storage format of a value is something you cannot and **you should not** consider as *something to rely on*... This might be a case of an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... Please provide some more details, what you really want to achieve and I'm pretty sure, that there is a better approach...

Comment: I'm trying to marshal data of various types into a service broker message.  I convert other types to binary (varchar, integers, floats, etc.) with no problems and as far as I know there's no warnings on other types.  But I still need to be able to convert decimal types as well efficiently and robustly.

Comment: Brian, I'd strongly advise not to do so! The internal representation may change, strings might vary (utf-16, extended ASCII, encoding of special characters / collation dependancy), float storage is quite complex on its own, decimals use various patterns internally... You cannot rely on a bit pattern... What exactly do you mean with *marshal to a service broker message*?

Comment: I am sending a lot of data using [service broker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166104%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) between servers and need something more efficient than text or XML so i need to [marshal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) the data.

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: Currently 2008 R2 but will be migrating to 2014 or 2016 before the end of the year I'm guessing.

Comment: With 2016 there is JSON-support. Would it help to create a JSON (or a little fatter XML) and marshal the whole thing in one? Doing so, you get all data converted to a defined **string** format...

Comment: Have you considered using a sql_variant to store variant data.A column of type sql_variant may contain rows of different data types

Answer (score 4):

Let's start from `DATALENGTH`. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx):

> DATALENGTH is especially useful with varchar, varbinary, text, image,
>   nvarchar, and ntext data types because these data types can store
>   variable-length data.

The minimum length of decimal is 5 bytes, maximum - 17 bytes. `Decimal(p,s)` is NOT variable-length data. It has fixed length according to precision. For example if length of numeric is from 1 to 9 number then `DATALENGTH` will always return 5

```
select DATALENGTH(convert(Decimal(38,0), 1)) -- result 5
select DATALENGTH(convert(Decimal(38,0), 1234567890)) -- result 5
```

if length of numeric is from 10 to 19 number then `DATALENGTH` will always return 9

```
select DATALENGTH(convert(Decimal(38,0), 12345678901)) -- result 9
select DATALENGTH(convert(Decimal(38,0), 111111111111111)) -- result 9
```

so, result of `DATALENGTH` will depend of numeric's lenght but it is not real lenght.

When you convert `decimal(4,0)` to `binary(5)` you will get `0x04 00 00 01 00`
In this case, only the last byte is left for your number. The maximum number that you can store in 1 byte is `255` (`255` in HEX equals `FF`)

In that way everything works fine:

```
DECLARE @myval decimal (4, 0);  
SET @myval = 255;  
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(4,0), CONVERT(binary(5), @myval)) result, CONVERT(binary(5), @myval)

result                                  HEX
--------------------------------------- ------------
255                                     0x04000001FF
```

Now, try number `256` instead of `255`. `256` in HEX equals `100`, we can't store `100` in 1 byte (HEX should be 0x04 00 00 01 00 *1* but there is not room for *1*)

```
DECLARE @myval decimal (4, 0);  
SET @myval = 256;  
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(4,0), CONVERT(binary(5), @myval)) result, CONVERT(binary(5), @myval) HEX
result                                  HEX
--------------------------------------- ------------
0                                       0x0400000100
```

If you want to store numbers from 0 to 9999 then you need at least 6 bytes. Look at `257` (in HEX equals `101`)

```
DECLARE @myval decimal (4, 0);  
SET @myval = 257;  
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(4,0), CONVERT(binary(6), @myval)) result, CONVERT(binary(6), @myval) HEX
result                                  HEX
--------------------------------------- --------------
256                                     0x040000010101
```

here we have 6 bytes `0x04 00 00 01 01 01` and `01 01` in the end
Then `9999` (HEX equals `270F`)

```
DECLARE @myval decimal (4, 0);  
SET @myval = 9999;  
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(4,0), CONVERT(binary(6), @myval)) result, CONVERT(binary(6), @myval) HEX
result                                  HEX
--------------------------------------- --------------
9999                                    0x040000010F27
```

6 bytes `0x04 00 00 01 0F 27` and `27 0F` in the end. (read from right to left)

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question.  I know that it requires 6 byes to store decimal(4,0), I stated that in my question.  My question is what is the general rule for determining the minimum binary size for decimal(p,s).  If there's not one, how do I marshal decimal values in binary in a robust way?

Comment: I'm sorry but there weren't any info in the question about data marshaling when I've answered. You asked "What is happening?" and "how do I know how many bytes will be needed?". Here I tried to describe how it works. I will look at your edited question and try to help later

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't as clear as I could have been at first.  Thanks for looking at it with me!

Answer (score 3):

The documentation states that it uses 5 bytes of storage.  It does not state that it takes 5 bytes when converting it to varbinary(N) using CAST or CONVERT.  Infact, the documentation warns you NOT to cast numeric types to/from binary with the [following note](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

> Do not try to construct binary values and then convert them to a data
>   type of the numeric data type category. SQL Server does not guarantee
>   that the result of a decimal or numeric data type conversion to binary
>   will be the same between versions of SQL Server.

I suspect that when converting a numeric to varbinary it is including precision and scale information, in addition to the data bits. When stored in a table, this information is defined by the schema so it doesn't need to store the precision and scale for each value, only the data bits.

Comment: I saw that note, and right above it in that article it does exactly what it appears to say not to do.  But as long as i'm not storing this binary data for use on another server without testing, I think it's ok to do.  But how do I know how many bytes of binary I need to store a decimal?

Comment: @BrianPressler, you can always use long enough `varbinary`, say 50 to guarantee that the binary representation of the decimal value is not clipped. Just try to convert few `decimal` values into `varbinary` yourself and you'll see that there seems to be a 3-byte prefix that describes the precision and scale of the value. In practice, you should not rely on this in production and you should store `decimal` values in the column of the `decimal` type, not `(var)binary` type.

Comment: I'm doing some binary data marshaling into a service broker message, so I need to keep the values small as possible.  Is that the rule... there's always a 3 byte prefix to the binary conversion?  Do you have a source for this?

Comment: The point is that it is undocumented.  Experimentation shows a prefix, and explains the original question of why it is longer than the documented internal storage data length.  If you write code based on this experimentation, Microsoft has already warned in the documentation that the format is subject to change, which implies the length is subject to change, too.

Comment: @BrianPressler, to marshal the data, I'd convert `decimal` to `varchar` of suitable length using, say, `STR`. If you use only `decimal(4,0)`, then simple `char(4)` is already better than 5 binary bytes. Or you can invent your own binary representation of the decimal value and write some custom code to pack and unpack the values. In this case you'd know the format of the binary values and not rely on the undocumented reverse engineered guesses and it will not suddenly change when the version of SQL Server changes.

Comment: Converting to string works fine for numbers with low precision, but not efficient otherwise.  I need to marshal a lot of data of various types so the conversion needs to be quick and compact as possible.  The convert function seems to accomplish this, but I don't like that the documentation makes it sound flaky for decimal values.  Still not sure what the best approach is.

Comment: @BrianPressler, the easy, but fragile way is to convert your `decimal` into `varbinary(some large enough value)` instead of fixed-sized `binary`. Server will decide how many bytes it needs. This easy way also doesn't guarantee you the smallest binary value possible. I don't think there is any documentation on how exactly the server converts values of different types into `(var)binary)`. You already saw that this conversion does **not** produce the same binary value that is stored on the disk. Depending on your data and its volume, consider compressing it with something like gzip before sending

Answer (score 2):

Binary datatype in SQL obviously uses an encoding scheme which depends upon the source datatype. Try running the following and see what results you get:

```
SELECT CAST(256 AS Binary(8)), 
       CAST(CAST(256 as decimal(4,0)) AS Binary(8)),  
       CAST(CAST(256 as decimal(9,6)) AS Binary(8)), 
       CAST(CAST(256 as float(2)) AS Binary(8))
```

Note that you get the following results:

```
0x0000000000000100  0x0400000100010000  0x090600010040420F  0x0000000043800000
```

This shows that when a decimal is converted to a Binary, the binary contains encoding showing how long the decimal is and how many decimal places. You can also see that you get a different binary representation depending upon these. It is also clear that integer and floats are encoded differently. I think this explains why you are getting truncation.

Not quite an answer to why but if you can change your table then you could specify the column as a sql_variant:

```
declare @test sql_variant


SET @test = 'I''m a string'


SELECT  @test As Col,
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@test,'BaseType') AS 'Base Type',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@test,'Precision') AS 'Precision',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@test,'Scale') AS 'Scale'
```

**Result**

```
Col             Base Type   Precision   Scale
I'm a string    varchar     0           0
```

Now try with a decmal:

```
SET @test = 1.2

SELECT  @test As Col,
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@test,'BaseType') AS 'Base Type',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@test,'Precision') AS 'Precision',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@test,'Scale') AS 'Scale'
```

**Result**

```
Col Base Type   Precision   Scale
1.2 numeric     2           1
```

Answer (score 2):

You **should not rely on a bit pattern unless *you can control* its format!**

If I understand you correctly, you want to transfer large amount of data and you want to do this as fast and secure as possible.

The only way I know to get a reliable bit pattern is a **defined conversion to string**.
`FOR XML` (and starting with 2016 `FOR JSON`) uses well defined string formats **to guarantee type safety**.

The following example will create an XML with various types, cast this to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and cast this intermediate string to a binary. This binary is plain `unicode` and will be interpreted by (almost) any system correctly.

Just to demonstrate, that this bit pattern is safely re-casteable and re-readable into typed results I show the reading process too:

```
DECLARE @Source NVARCHAR(MAX)=
CAST(
(
    SELECT 'Some varchar string' AS SimpleString
          ,N'Some nvarchar string with foreign characters: слов в тексте' AS WideString
          ,CAST(100.0/3.0 AS DECIMAL(10,4)) AS Decimal_10_4
          ,CAST(100.0/3.0 AS FLOAT(12)) AS Float_12
          ,CAST(100.0/3.0 AS FLOAT(53)) AS Float_53
          ,GETDATE() AS SimpleDateTime
          ,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME2) AS ExtDateTime
    FOR XML RAW,ELEMENTS
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX));

SELECT @Source;
```

--this is the intermediate XML

```
/*
<row>
  <SimpleString>Some varchar string</SimpleString>
  <WideString>Some nvarchar string with foreign characters: слов в тексте</WideString>
  <Decimal_10_4>33.3333</Decimal_10_4>
  <Float_12>3.3333332e+001</Float_12>
  <Float_53>3.333333300000000e+001</Float_53>
  <SimpleDateTime>2017-03-20T09:28:10.873</SimpleDateTime>
  <ExtDateTime>2017-03-20T09:28:10.8730000</ExtDateTime>
</row>
*/
```

--Now we can cast this to `VARBINARY` in order to send it somewhere

```
DECLARE @binaryToMarshal VARBINARY(MAX)=CAST(@Source AS VARBINARY(MAX));
```

--The rest is the **type-safe!** reading side:

```
DECLARE @Target NVARCHAR(MAX)=CAST(@binaryToMarshal AS NVARCHAR(MAX));

DECLARE @ReCastes XML=CAST(@Target AS XML);

SELECT @ReCastes.value('(/row/SimpleString)[1]','varchar(max)') AS SimpleString
      ,@ReCastes.value('(/row/WideString)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS WideString
      ,@ReCastes.value('(/row/Decimal_10_4)[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS Decimal_10_4
      ,@ReCastes.value('(/row/Float_12)[1]','float(12)') AS Float_12
      ,@ReCastes.value('(/row/Float_53)[1]','float(53)') AS Float_53
      ,@ReCastes.value('(/row/SimpleDateTime)[1]','datetime') AS SimpleDateTime
      ,@ReCastes.value('(/row/ExtDateTime)[1]','datetime2') AS ExtDateTime
```

### Hint 1

You might use `FOR XML RAW,ELEMENTS,XMLSCHEMA` to create an inline schema. This schema allows the target system, to know all needed details for a typed reading.

### Hint 2

As you want to save bytes, you might use minimal element names and `JSON`.

And - if you do not include special characters - you might send only half the size by using `CAST ... AS VARCHAR(MAX)`. In this case you do not send `utf-16` but `1-byte-codes *(extended ASCII)*` which should be readable on any system unless you do not need any code page, collation, whatever...

Answer (score 2):

according to MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms188362.aspx

> varbinary [ ( n | max) ]:
>   Variable-length binary data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. **The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes**. The data that is entered can be 0 bytes in length. The ANSI SQL synonym for varbinary is binary varying.

When you declare

```
DECLARE @myval decimal (4, 0);
```

you define a 4 digit decimal number that can store -9999 to +9999.
to convert it to/from varbinary you should use/expect +2 extra bytes in varbinary type:

```
DECLARE @myval decimal (4, 0);  
SET @myval = 9999;  
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(4,0), CONVERT(varbinary(6), @myval)) result
```

note that `precision` parameter in `decimal` determines the maximum total number of decimal digits and not maximum value in binary.

Answer (score 1):

when you cast to varbinary you not only dump value (which can take up to 5 bytes in your case) but also information about type hence you need extra byte to fit everything in your case.

Consider that if you switch the source data type from decimal (4,0) to decimal (5,0) you will get different varbinary result.

All in all I recommend to not play with varbinary :)